# Is there a command to spawn a baby zombie?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a command to spawn a baby zombie? I've searched on YouTube and Google but all I could find was how to spawn a chicken jockey and how to spawn a zombie pigman.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `IsBaby` tag will state whether or not the zombie is a baby. Making it 1 will enable the zombie to be a baby.

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~1 ~ {IsBaby:1b}
```

Comment: the mob name is now minecraft:zombie